# AmplifyJS, IE11 strange storage choice (Memory vs. localStorage)

Tags: internet-explorer, amplifyjs

Why **AmplifyJS** uses different storage types in the following two cases:

1. For this [online example](http://bl.ocks.org/jugglingnutcase/raw/4608328/1e93dbc9e03f9a6acf2326faa52d432b175ec998/) AmplifyJS uses **localStorage in IE11**, so the saved value is visible on different tabs.
2. But when I save the page and run it locally, AmplifyJS chooses a **Memory storage**. As result the stored value is 'underfined' when we try to retrieve it from other tabs.

I see the issue for IE11 only. Chrome and Firefox work fine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage is [not available for *local* files in IE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/61177c2b-6a38-4207-9cbe-ccd6c86b1d42/html5-local-storage-broken-in-ie11-win-81-x64-error-function-expected?forum=iewebdevelopment), so it looks like Amplify.js is defaulting to the next available storage type: http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/